# Declaring pilotID AS INT = 1 in SQL, but I need it to be 1, then 2, then 3 (LOOPING)

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I have a monstrous query, that if you can completely understand, I will give you some serious props:

```
DECLARE @flightDateOrNow DATE = GETDATE()
DECLARE @pilotID INT = 1

SELECT P7.pilotID 
FROM Pilot P7
WHERE location = 'DPG';


SELECT P1.pilotID, BasicInfo.lName, BasicInfo.fName, 
        PilotExamTemp.examType, PilotExamTemp.examDate,

        (CASE
            WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                         FROM PilotGFRCertification 
                         WHERE pilotID = @pilotID 
                            AND certificationPosition = 'AVO'
                            AND certification = 'TNG')
                AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                                 FROM PilotGFRCertification 
                                 WHERE pilotID = @pilotID 
                                    AND certificationPosition = 'AVO'
                                    AND certification = 'AVO')
                THEN 'X'
            ELSE ''
         END) TNG,

         (CASE
            WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                         FROM PilotGFRCertification 
                         WHERE pilotID = @pilotID 
                            AND certificationPosition = 'AVO'
                            AND certification = 'AVO')
                THEN 'X'
            ELSE ''
         END) AVO,

        (CASE
            WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                         FROM PilotGFRCertification 
                         WHERE pilotID = @pilotID 
                            AND certificationPosition = 'AVO'
                            AND certification = 'MC')
                THEN 'X'
            ELSE ''
         END) MC,

        (CASE
            WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                         FROM PilotGFRCertification 
                         WHERE pilotID = @pilotID 
                            AND certificationPosition = 'AVO'
                            AND certification = 'IO')
                THEN 'X'
            ELSE ''
         END) [IO],

        (CASE
            WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                         FROM PilotGFRCertification 
                         WHERE pilotID = @pilotID 
                            AND certificationPosition = 'AVO'
                            AND certification = 'SO')
                THEN 'X'
            ELSE ''
         END) SO,

         ISNULL((SELECT SUM(P3.flightHours) MCTotal
          FROM PilotLog P3
          WHERE P3.pilotID = P1.pilotID
            AND (flightDate <= P1.flightDate)
            AND topLevelPosition = 'AVO'
            AND dutyStation = 'MC'
         ), 0) MCTotal,

         ISNULL((SELECT SUM(P3.flightHours) AVOTotal
          FROM PilotLog P3
          WHERE P3.pilotID = P1.pilotID
            AND (flightDate <= P1.flightDate)
            AND topLevelPosition = 'AVO'
            AND dutyStation <> 'MC'
         ), 0) AVOTotal,

         (SELECT DATEADD(day, 60, (SELECT TOP 1 flightDate 
                                    FROM PilotLog P3
                                    WHERE P3.flightDate < P1.flightDate
                                        AND P3.topLevelPosition = 'AVO'
                                        AND P3.dutyStation = 'MC'
                                    ORDER BY P3.flightDate DESC))

         ) currency60Day,
         (  
            SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM PilotLog P4 
            WHERE P4.pilotID = @pilotID  
                AND topLevelPosition = 'AVO'
                AND sortieGained = 'True'
                AND (P4.flightDate BETWEEN (CASE     
                                           WHEN P1.flightDate > (DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID), P1.flightDate) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID))))), DATEADD(m,7,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID), P1.flightDate) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID))))))   )), DATEADD(m,7,(DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID), P1.flightDate) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID))))), DATEADD(m,7,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID), P1.flightDate) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID))))))   )))    
                                                THEN (DATEADD(yyyy, 1, (DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID), P1.flightDate) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID)))))-1),DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID), P1.flightDate) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID)))))) ))    
                                           WHEN P1.flightDate > (DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID), P1.flightDate) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID))))), DATEADD(m,7,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID), P1.flightDate) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID))))))       
                                                THEN (DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID), P1.flightDate) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID)))))-1),DATEADD(m,7,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID), P1.flightDate) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID))))))        
                                           ELSE (DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID), P1.flightDate) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID)))))-1),DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID), P1.flightDate) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID))))))    
                                        End) 
                                        AND 
                                        (P1.flightDate))) semiSorties,
        (  
            SELECT SUM(P4.flightHours)
            FROM PilotLog P4 
            WHERE P4.pilotID = @pilotID  
                AND topLevelPosition = 'AVO'
                AND sortieGained = 'True'
                AND (P4.flightDate BETWEEN (CASE     
                                           WHEN P1.flightDate > (DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID), P1.flightDate) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID))))), DATEADD(m,7,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID), P1.flightDate) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID))))))   )), DATEADD(m,7,(DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID), P1.flightDate) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID))))), DATEADD(m,7,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID), P1.flightDate) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID))))))   )))    
                                                THEN (DATEADD(yyyy, 1, (DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID), P1.flightDate) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID)))))-1),DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID), P1.flightDate) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID)))))) ))    
                                           WHEN P1.flightDate > (DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID), P1.flightDate) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID))))), DATEADD(m,7,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID), P1.flightDate) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID))))))       
                                                THEN (DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID), P1.flightDate) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID)))))-1),DATEADD(m,7,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID), P1.flightDate) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID))))))        
                                           ELSE (DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID), P1.flightDate) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID)))))-1),DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID), P1.flightDate) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID))))))    
                                        End) 
                                        AND 
                                        (P1.flightDate))) semiSortieHours,

        (CASE     
           WHEN @flightDateOrNow > (DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID), @flightDateOrNow) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID))))), DATEADD(m,7,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID), @flightDateOrNow) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID))))))   )), DATEADD(m,7,(DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID), @flightDateOrNow) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID))))), DATEADD(m,7,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID), @flightDateOrNow) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID))))))   )))    
                THEN (DATEADD(yyyy, 1, (DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID), @flightDateOrNow) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID))))), DATEADD(m,7,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID), @flightDateOrNow) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID))))))   ))    
           WHEN @flightDateOrNow > (DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID), @flightDateOrNow) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID))))), DATEADD(m,7,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID), @flightDateOrNow) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID))))))        
                THEN (DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID), @flightDateOrNow) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID))))), DATEADD(m,13,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID), @flightDateOrNow) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID))))))      
           ELSE (DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID), @flightDateOrNow) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID))))), DATEADD(m,7,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID), @flightDateOrNow) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID))))))      
        End) semiEnd,


        (CASE   
            WHEN @flightDateOrNow > (DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, (DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID), @flightDateOrNow)) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID))) )), DATEADD(m,13,(DATEADD(yyyy, (DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID), @flightDateOrNow)) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID))) ))) THEN (DATEADD(yyyy, 1, (DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, (DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID), @flightDateOrNow)) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID))) )), DATEADD(m,13,(DATEADD(yyyy, (DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID), @flightDateOrNow)) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID))) )))))  
            ELSE (DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, (DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID), @flightDateOrNow)) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID))) )), DATEADD(m,13,(DATEADD(yyyy, (DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID), @flightDateOrNow)) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = @pilotID))) )))  
        END) annualEnd,

        PMTemp.expirationDate, PMTemp.classFAAMedical


FROM PilotLog P1, Pilot BasicInfo,
        (SELECT DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(m,1, medicalDate)), DATEADD(m,13,medicalDate)) expirationDate, classFAAMedical  
         FROM PilotMedical  
         WHERE (pilotID = @pilotID)  
            AND medicalDate = (SELECT MAX(medicalDate) FROM PilotMedical WHERE pilotID = @pilotID)) AS PMTemp,
        (SELECT *
         FROM PilotExam
         WHERE (pilotID = @pilotID)
            AND examPosition = 'AVO'
            AND examDate = (SELECT MAX(examDate) FROM PilotExam WHERE pilotID = @pilotID AND examPosition = 'AVO')) AS PilotExamTemp


WHERE P1.pilotID = @pilotID 
    AND P1.topLevelPosition = 'AVO'
    AND P1.pilotID = BasicInfo.pilotID
    AND P1.flightDate = (SELECT MAX(P5.flightDate) FROM PilotLog P5 WHERE pilotID = @pilotID)
    ORDER BY flightDate DESC
```

This results in:

```
pilotID
1
2
3
4
5


pilotID lName   fName   examType    examDate    TNG AVO MC  IO  SO  MCTotal AVOTotal    currency60Day   semiSorties semiSortieHours    semiEnd  annualEnd   expirationDate  classFAAMedical
1       Wilkins Landon  Written     2012-10-11      X   X   X       16.3    7.0          2012-08-14       2         16.7             2012-10-31 2012-10-31  2013-04-30         Third
```

But what I want is the real long line for each of those pilotIDs. Is there an easy way to do this? Or do I have to completely restructure my SQL? (BTW, the really hairy part of that SQL is me figuring out the pilot's semi annual start and end period, as it is based on their birth month. Quite annoying really)

EDIT #1:

I have it mostly working with the following:

```
DECLARE @flightDateOrNow DATE = GETDATE()


SELECT P7.pilotID 
FROM Pilot P7
WHERE location = 'DPG';


SELECT DISTINCT BasicInfo.pilotID, BasicInfo.lName, BasicInfo.fName,

        (CASE
            WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                         FROM PilotGFRCertification 
                         WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID 
                            AND certificationPosition = 'AVO'
                            AND certification = 'TNG')
                AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                                 FROM PilotGFRCertification 
                                 WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID 
                                    AND certificationPosition = 'AVO'
                                    AND certification = 'AVO')
                THEN 'X'
            ELSE ''
         END) TNG,

         (CASE
            WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                         FROM PilotGFRCertification 
                         WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID 
                            AND certificationPosition = 'AVO'
                            AND certification = 'AVO')
                THEN 'X'
            ELSE ''
         END) AVO,

        (CASE
            WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                         FROM PilotGFRCertification 
                         WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID 
                            AND certificationPosition = 'AVO'
                            AND certification = 'MC')
                THEN 'X'
            ELSE ''
         END) MC,

        (CASE
            WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                         FROM PilotGFRCertification 
                         WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID 
                            AND certificationPosition = 'AVO'
                            AND certification = 'IO')
                THEN 'X'
            ELSE ''
         END) [IO],

        (CASE
            WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                         FROM PilotGFRCertification 
                         WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID 
                            AND certificationPosition = 'AVO'
                            AND certification = 'SO')
                THEN 'X'
            ELSE ''
         END) SO,

         ISNULL((SELECT SUM(P3.flightHours) MCTotal
          FROM PilotLog P3
          WHERE P3.pilotID = P1.pilotID
            AND (flightDate <= (SELECT MAX(P5.flightDate) FROM PilotLog P5 WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID))
            AND topLevelPosition = 'AVO'
            AND dutyStation = 'MC'
         ), 0) MCTotal,

         ISNULL((SELECT SUM(P3.flightHours) AVOTotal
          FROM PilotLog P3
          WHERE P3.pilotID = P1.pilotID
            AND (flightDate <= (SELECT MAX(P5.flightDate) FROM PilotLog P5 WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID))
            AND topLevelPosition = 'AVO'
            AND dutyStation <> 'MC'
         ), 0) AVOTotal,

         (SELECT DATEADD(day, 60, (SELECT TOP 1 flightDate 
                                    FROM PilotLog P3
                                    WHERE P3.flightDate < (SELECT MAX(P5.flightDate) FROM PilotLog P5 WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID)
                                        AND P3.topLevelPosition = 'AVO'
                                        AND P3.dutyStation = 'MC'
                                    ORDER BY P3.flightDate DESC))

         ) currency60Day,
         (  
            SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM PilotLog P4 
            WHERE P4.pilotID = P1.pilotID  
                AND topLevelPosition = 'AVO'
                AND sortieGained = 'True'
                AND (P4.flightDate BETWEEN (CASE     
                                           WHEN (SELECT MAX(P5.flightDate) FROM PilotLog P5 WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID) > (DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID), (SELECT MAX(P5.flightDate) FROM PilotLog P5 WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID)) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID))))), DATEADD(m,7,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID), (SELECT MAX(P5.flightDate) FROM PilotLog P5 WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID)) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID))))))   )), DATEADD(m,7,(DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID), (SELECT MAX(P5.flightDate) FROM PilotLog P5 WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID)) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID))))), DATEADD(m,7,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID), (SELECT MAX(P5.flightDate) FROM PilotLog P5 WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID)) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID))))))   )))    
                                                THEN (DATEADD(yyyy, 1, (DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID), (SELECT MAX(P5.flightDate) FROM PilotLog P5 WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID)) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID)))))-1),DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID), (SELECT MAX(P5.flightDate) FROM PilotLog P5 WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID)) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID)))))) ))    
                                           WHEN (SELECT MAX(P5.flightDate) FROM PilotLog P5 WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID) > (DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID), (SELECT MAX(P5.flightDate) FROM PilotLog P5 WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID)) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID))))), DATEADD(m,7,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID), (SELECT MAX(P5.flightDate) FROM PilotLog P5 WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID)) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID))))))       
                                                THEN (DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID), (SELECT MAX(P5.flightDate) FROM PilotLog P5 WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID)) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID)))))-1),DATEADD(m,7,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID), (SELECT MAX(P5.flightDate) FROM PilotLog P5 WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID)) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID))))))        
                                           ELSE (DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID), (SELECT MAX(P5.flightDate) FROM PilotLog P5 WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID)) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID)))))-1),DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID), (SELECT MAX(P5.flightDate) FROM PilotLog P5 WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID)) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID))))))    
                                        End) 
                                        AND 
                                        ((SELECT MAX(P5.flightDate) FROM PilotLog P5 WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID)))) semiSorties,
        (  
            SELECT SUM(P4.flightHours)
            FROM PilotLog P4 
            WHERE P4.pilotID = P1.pilotID  
                AND topLevelPosition = 'AVO'
                AND sortieGained = 'True'
                AND (P4.flightDate BETWEEN (CASE     
                                           WHEN (SELECT MAX(P5.flightDate) FROM PilotLog P5 WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID) > (DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID), (SELECT MAX(P5.flightDate) FROM PilotLog P5 WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID)) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID))))), DATEADD(m,7,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID), (SELECT MAX(P5.flightDate) FROM PilotLog P5 WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID)) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID))))))   )), DATEADD(m,7,(DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID), (SELECT MAX(P5.flightDate) FROM PilotLog P5 WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID)) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID))))), DATEADD(m,7,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID), (SELECT MAX(P5.flightDate) FROM PilotLog P5 WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID)) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID))))))   )))    
                                                THEN (DATEADD(yyyy, 1, (DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID), (SELECT MAX(P5.flightDate) FROM PilotLog P5 WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID)) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID)))))-1),DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID), (SELECT MAX(P5.flightDate) FROM PilotLog P5 WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID)) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID)))))) ))    
                                           WHEN (SELECT MAX(P5.flightDate) FROM PilotLog P5 WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID) > (DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID), (SELECT MAX(P5.flightDate) FROM PilotLog P5 WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID)) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID))))), DATEADD(m,7,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID), (SELECT MAX(P5.flightDate) FROM PilotLog P5 WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID)) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID))))))       
                                                THEN (DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID), (SELECT MAX(P5.flightDate) FROM PilotLog P5 WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID)) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID)))))-1),DATEADD(m,7,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID), (SELECT MAX(P5.flightDate) FROM PilotLog P5 WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID)) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID))))))        
                                           ELSE (DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID), (SELECT MAX(P5.flightDate) FROM PilotLog P5 WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID)) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID)))))-1),DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID), (SELECT MAX(P5.flightDate) FROM PilotLog P5 WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID)) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID))))))    
                                        End) 
                                        AND 
                                        ((SELECT MAX(P5.flightDate) FROM PilotLog P5 WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID)))) semiSortieHours,

        (CASE     
           WHEN @flightDateOrNow > (DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID), @flightDateOrNow) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID))))), DATEADD(m,7,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID), @flightDateOrNow) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID))))))   )), DATEADD(m,7,(DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID), @flightDateOrNow) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID))))), DATEADD(m,7,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID), @flightDateOrNow) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID))))))   )))    
                THEN (DATEADD(yyyy, 1, (DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID), @flightDateOrNow) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID))))), DATEADD(m,7,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID), @flightDateOrNow) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID))))))   ))    
           WHEN @flightDateOrNow > (DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID), @flightDateOrNow) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID))))), DATEADD(m,7,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID), @flightDateOrNow) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID))))))        
                THEN (DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID), @flightDateOrNow) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID))))), DATEADD(m,13,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID), @flightDateOrNow) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID))))))      
           ELSE (DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID), @flightDateOrNow) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID))))), DATEADD(m,7,(DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID), @flightDateOrNow) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID))))))      
        End) semiEnd,


        (CASE   
            WHEN @flightDateOrNow > (DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, (DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID), @flightDateOrNow)) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID))) )), DATEADD(m,13,(DATEADD(yyyy, (DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID), @flightDateOrNow)) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID))) ))) THEN (DATEADD(yyyy, 1, (DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, (DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID), @flightDateOrNow)) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID))) )), DATEADD(m,13,(DATEADD(yyyy, (DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID), @flightDateOrNow)) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID))) )))))  
            ELSE (DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(m,1,(DATEADD(yyyy, (DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID), @flightDateOrNow)) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID))) )), DATEADD(m,13,(DATEADD(yyyy, (DATEDIFF(yy, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID), @flightDateOrNow)) - 1, (SELECT birthDate FROM Pilot WHERE pilotID = P1.pilotID))) )))  
        END) annualEnd



FROM PilotLog P1
FULL JOIN Pilot BasicInfo
    ON P1.pilotID = BasicInfo.pilotID

WHERE 
    BasicInfo.location = 'DPG'
```

Now for the schema (in process of uploading them, here are a couple tables so far)

Pilot
[image: Pilot Table]

Pilot Log
[image]

Pilot Exam
[image]

PilotGFRCertification
[image]

PilotMedical
[image]

Comment: Holy monstrous query, Batman!  You're already selecting `BasicInfo.lName, BasicInfo.fName`, etc., so I'm confused as to why you aren't getting the long line in your example?

Comment: i dont understand... are you looking to just group by the pilotid with all this information....?  or what does "a really long line" mean? and you're only selecting one pilot, right?  with the parameter?  is that what you want or...? sorry.  im lost.  you're using a lot of nested select statements... you probably don't have to keep retrieving that data over and over again like that.  can we see table structures maybe?  i dunno... (OMG it's little bobby tables!)

Comment: also... you should try to use joins instead of just doing it in the where clause.... probably.... good practice.  easier to read.... on the up and up.

Comment: LittleBobbyTables: Well, I'm actually executing two... wait a minute, something just occured to me, I'm going to try something

@gloomy.penguin : Essentially, I'm only selected one pilot right now, when I want to select all of that data given in the second result (pilotID, lName, fName, examType, examDate, etc.) for each of those pilot IDs. And I'll post my schemas here in a minute, I think I may have figured something out!

Comment: @Silver - Derp, I see that now. You could replace `WHERE pilotID = @pilotID` with a query against `SELECT P7.pilotID FROM Pilot P7 WHERE location = 'DPG'`. This query really is calling for derived tables.

Comment: yeah.  really... the answer to his problem was actually in question posted on top: "but I need it to be 1, then 2, then 3 (LOOPING)"

Comment: I updated with schema, I'm attempting some of the answers now, will post soon with an update of progress/success (hopefully success). If you can see a better means of attacking this, please I'm all ears!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

- define a table variable to hold your pilot ID's you want to deal with

  ```
  DECLARE @PilotIDs TABLE (PilotID INT)

  INSERT INTO @PilotIDs 
     SELECT P7.pilotID 
     FROM Pilot P7
     WHERE location = 'DPG';
  ```
- in the beginning (in the list of columns to be selected), you have this condition a few times:

  ```
  WHERE pilotID = @pilotID
  ```

  replace that with:

  ```
  WHERE pilotID = P1.PilotID
  ```
- leave the rest of your query alone - at the very end you have a few conditions like

  ```
  WHERE P1.pilotID = @pilotID
  ```

  change those to be:

  ```
  WHERE P1.pilotID IN (SELECT PilotID FROM @PilotIDs)
  ```

And that *should* basically take care of it - I hope! This is a really big huge ugly monster of a query... I hope that doesn't break anything somewhere in the middle of QueryZilla ......

Comment: Attempting this now, looks promising! QueryZilla is exactly what that thing is, it makes me cringe. I don't know how to do it better though.

Comment: I didn't quite do your answer, but I did use your sub table solution and it worked, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

At a glance, I believe that changing your last `SELECT` statement with the following two changes should get the results you're looking for:

1. Replace all instances of `@pilotID` with `P1.PilotID`
2. Remove the `WHERE` clause of `P1.pilotID = @pilotID`

I would be curious to see the overall schema though, as this looks like it could be written as a bit of a shorter query taking advantage of some lookup tables and JOINs instead.